# specifying a range the last of which is the penultimate line

Tags: range

I have 69 files in which I want to prepend lines 5 to penultimate with a short string. How could I address the penultimate line? `:5,61s/^/X/g` would do it if I manually look up that the last line is 62, but if I want to script it for all the files, how can I do that? I could imagine doing something like 

`` vim "+:5,$((`cat test.txt|wc -l` - 1))s/^/X/g|:x" test.txt ``

from the command line, but as I'm not dealing with a simple search and replace as in my above example I think I won't be able to provide it from the command line, how can I do it from within vim?

Comment: `$-1` could be used to express the second to last line. Does `:5,$-1s/^/X` work for you?

Comment: @user9433424 Yes, that seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express the penultimate line with `$-1`. So, in your case, to prepend `X` in front of all the lines from the fifth down to the second to last one, you could use the following substitution command:

```
:5,$-1s/^/X
```

You can find more information on how to write a range in `:help :range`.

Comment: `-1` in a range can be shorted to `-` as the `1` can be assumed. e.g. `:5,$-s/^/X`